Soft close drawer slamming shut
I noticed an issue where on of the drawers in my bathroom was slamming shut, I took out the drawer and noticed the slides on either sides were slamming shut. To confirm my findings I removed a working drawer but found the right side soft closed the left slammed shut. comparison
I feel like if I could just adjust the spring on the left side I could solve the issue with the slamming drawer, but I've found no resources on how to do that. I can't even find a manufacturer for these things, I feel like I'm nearing my wits end.

It's not the spring - it's the damper (the little rod and cylinder). The damper is supposed to resist the pressure from the closing spring to make it soft-close.

It looks like the damper is not doing it's job anymore. It may have leaked or a gasket is worn on the inside. Without knowing the manufacturer it's impossible to know if that's a replaceable part or not. Look for a model number stamped somewhere on the side.
If you can't find the replacement part or identical slide, you may have to retrofit new drawer slides from a different manufacturer. That process can range from easy to very difficult depending on how the new slides fit and operate.
This looks very similar to what you have https://www.amazon.ca/Undermount-Extension-Concealed-Mounting-Brackets/dp/B097PKKCT4

Google "soft close drawer slides."
Or go to Rockler.com. They have many slides. This centerline set looks like it may be what you have.
You will need to determine the length for an exact replacement.
